# Is there something like bpython for Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, ide, irb, bpython

IRb is pretty plain compared to [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org/screenshots/), even when using [wirble](http://www.rubyinside.com/wirble-tab-completion-and-syntax-coloring-for-irb-336.html).

Is there any ruby equivalent of bpython?

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed the wirble part of your question and replied about trying out wirble. I don't think that my post answers your question in any way so I have voted it for deletion.

Comment: @nas, no worries. Just an fyi: when you "vote" to delete your own answers, they are deleted immediately. I.e., I cannot see that you posted an answer here :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use Pry: http://pry.github.com

It is written from scratch and let's you:

- view method source code
- view method documentation (not using RI so you dont have to pre-generate it)
- pop in and out of different contexts
- invoke at runtime, in any context
- syntax highlighting
- gist integration
- view and replay history
- open editors to edit method using `edit-method obj.my_method` syntax

A tonne more great and original features

Answer (score 13):

You can extend irb to achieve all of bpython's functionality and more with the right gems:

- wirble: for syntax highlightning (as you already know)
- [bond](http://tagaholic.me/bond/): for more advanced autocompletion
- [utilitybelt](http://utilitybelt.rubyforge.org/): for pastebin-like commands
- [sketches](http://sketches.rubyforge.org): for editing and evaluating code easily
- [boson](http://tagaholic.me/boson/): command framework for creating libraries of commands to be loaded as needed
- [hirb](http://tagaholic.me/hirb/): framework for associating views per class

For more gems, [see here](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/irb_tools.html).

Comment: Ok, now someone should write a gem that pulls all these in and loads them nicely with irb.  Any takers? :-)

Comment: see this for your request, user83510: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884715/what-alternatives-to-irb-are-there